# Installing NVIDIA geforce 9 driver using the installer I got from their website

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hardware

In my ubuntu 12.10 it didn't detect my graphic card. When I check the graphics in system settings>details it says none

I've downloaded my driver installer from the NVIDIA website, make it executable, then it ran but it say I doesn't install on a X server..

I read in a blog that I have to download drivers via the software center called jockey. After the installation I couldn't find my driver in the list..plus the problem it mentioned if I messed up then it will mess up my boot.

Can't I just use the file I got from nvidia to install it? Speaking of which is it necessary here since I don't play games here and would go for vmware and install my old windows OS there and play the game there instead.

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't mean the card is not detected. Just use the built in installer, and don't forget to install `linux-headers-generic` first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

First put the downloaded NVIDIA driver in a folder which is easily accessible, for example on the `Desktop`.

Then switch to a virtual terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your username and password to login.

Navigate to the folder which you've placed your driver in it, in this case it is `Desktop`:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
```

Now add the permission : execute to the installation file:

```
sudo chmod +x NVIDIAdriver*.run
```

replace `NVIDIAdriver*` with the actual name.

Now stop the X server as the error also mentions the same thing:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Now you can go ahead and install the driver simply by typing this command:

```
sudo ./NVIDIAdriver*.run
```

Again replace `NVIDIAdriver*` with the drivers actual name.

Also, graphic cards don't support visualization yet, so you won't get any good performance with WMware.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   So far I've had the linux-headers-generic installed via the software center. And for using the virtual terminal I always end up stuck in it and when I press ctrl+alt+del it restarts the system.  I've tried using terminal so far nothing extraordinary appear when I did except that I end up with the virtual terminal and from there I tried entering the last terminal line: "sudo ./NVIDIAdriver*.run" but nothing..from there I couldn't get back to desktop.  thanks

Comment: you can revert back by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+f7` but before that you should enter the following command: `sudo service lightdm start`